# How to get distinct count of list on more than one property?

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to save list of admins and I need to validate unique username and email address. First, I need to validate that condition within the list of my request DTOs and then check it one at a time again with the list that is already saved in my database.

I checked RequestDTO using distinct once for username and email address.  Then again, I checked with the database. Doing this way, multiple loops are executed.

I referred following ways already :

[Java stream that is distinct by more than one property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45078255/java-stream-that-is-distinct-by-more-than-one-property)

[java 8 how to get distinct list on more than one property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42817884/java-8-how-to-get-distinct-list-on-more-than-one-property)

[Java 8 Distinct by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property)

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ApiModel(value = "This is admin request class")
public class AdminRequestDTO implements Serializable {

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "This is the id of admin")
    private Long id;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "This is the username of admin")
    private String username;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "This is full name of admin")
    private String fullName;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "This is the email address of admin")
    private String emailAddress;


    @ApiModelProperty(value = "This is the status of admin")
    private Character status;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "admin")
public class Admin implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "username")
  private String username;

  @Column(name = "fullname")
  private String fullName;

  @Column(name = "password")
  private String password;

  @Column(name = "email_address", length = 200)
  private String emailAddress;
}
```

```
public void saveAdmin(List<AdminRequestDTO> adminRequestDTO) {

    validateAdminRequestDTO.accept(adminRequestDTO);

    List<Admin> admin = adminRequestDTO.stream().map(requestDTO -> {

        /*CHECK IF USERNAME AND EMAIL ADDRESS IN REQUESTDTO EXISTS IN DATABASE, ID IT DOES, THEN THROW EXCEPTION*/
/*ELSE CONVERT */

        Admin admin1 = new Admin();
        admin1.setUsername(requestDTO.getUsername());
        /*SET OTHER REQUEST DTOS*/
        return admin1;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    /*SAVE ADMIN*/
    adminRepository.saveAll(admin);
}
```

```
  public Consumer<List<AdminRequestDTO>> validateAdminRequestDTO = (requestDTO) -> {

        boolean checkIfRequestHaveSameUsername = requestDTO.stream().map(AdminRequestDTO::getUsername)
                .distinct().count() < requestDTO.size();

        boolean checkIfRequestHaveSameEmailAddress = requestDTO.stream().map(AdminRequestDTO::getEmailAddress)
                .distinct().count() < requestDTO.size();

        if (checkIfRequestHaveSameUsername)
            throw new DataDuplicationException(AdminMessageConstants.DUPLICATE_USERNAME_MESSAGE,
                    AdminMessageConstants.DUPLICATE_USERNAME_DEVELOPER_MESSAGE);

        if (checkIfRequestHaveSameEmailAddress)
            throw new DataDuplicationException(AdminMessageConstants.DUPLICATE_EMAILADDRESS_MESSAGE,
                    AdminMessageConstants.DUPLICATE_EMAILADDRESS_DEVELOPER_MESSAGE);
    };
```

```
 public Consumer<AdminRequestDTO> validateAdmin = (requestDTO) -> {
        if (!Objects.isNull(adminRepository.getAdminByUsername(requestDTO.getUsername()))) ;
        throw new DataDuplicationException("Admin username already exits", "Admin username already exits");

            /*SIMILARLY FOR EMAIL ADDRESS*/
    };
```

I want to refactor the existing code so that the multiple loops could be reduced.

abc          abc@f1soft.com ,
xyz          xyz@f1soft.com   -> allowed

abc          abc@f1soft.com,
abc          xyz@f1soft.com     -> not allowed

abc          abc@f1soft.com,
xyz          abc@f1soft.com     -> not allowed

(first is username and second is email address)

Comment: You should not let the Java code do the database’s job. Besides that, when you refer to existing Q&As, you should also explain why you think that they do not solve your problem already.